# Exchange 2007: Which permissions required to change folder permissions for all mailboxes?

Tags: security, permissions, exchange, exchange-2007, windows

Which permission(s) are required to modify permissions on folders in all mailboxes in Exchange 2007?

I'm looking a least-privilege setup. I've seen hints pointing towards that the role `Organizational Administrator` is required, but this contradicts my wish of a least-privilege setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite.

[Check out this list of Mailbox permissions on Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd638132.aspx).  It's for Exchange 2010, and though I haven't checked exhaustively, it looks accurate for Exchange 2007 from my experience.

It states that managing mailbox folders requires one of `Organization Management`, `Recipient Management` or `Help Desk`.